# How to pass history to the Nav component inside the BrowserRouter in App.js

Tags: reactjs, router, history

I have the following code inside the App.js file:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Nav />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/barium" component={Barium} />
        <Route path="/gamma" component={Gamma} />
        <Route path="/h2spp" component={H2S} />
        <Route path="/texas" component={TexasGasEst} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/exam" component={Exam} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/students" component={Students} />
        <Route path="/*" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

In the Nav component I have a Login modal.
I want to pass the history prop to the Login modal through teh Nav component, in order to make a history.push right after login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<Nav>` is a descendant of `<BrowserRouter>` you can use the [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook inside it to get access to the History instance:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Nav() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function onAfterLogin() {
    history.push("/welcome");
  }

  // ...
}
```